# Display XML file into ListBox

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, binding

I'm new to WPF/C# programming. I'm trying to display a xml file content into a listbox using this XAML code :

```
<Window x:Class="test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="HostsData"
                   Source="/Hosts.xml"
                   XPath="Hosts/Host" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="98,70,0,0" Name="listBox1"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" SelectionChanged="listBox1_SelectionChanged"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource HostsData}}"
                 DisplayMemberPath="HostName"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And Hosts.xml contains :

```
<Hosts>
  <Host>
    <IP>1.1.1.1</IP>
    <HostName>abc01</HostName>
  </Host>
  <Host>
    <IP>2.2.2.2</IP>
    <HostName>abc02</HostName>
  </Host>
</Hosts>
```

I build successfully but when I run the app, the listbox is empty ! I've copied the Hosts.xml file everywhere but still nothing.

Any idea please ?

Comment: I just tested the same code without a SelectionChanged attribute and the listbox showed 2 elements. What do you mean with "I've copied the Hosts.xml file everywhere"?

Comment: When I add the XML file into the project, it's working fine, the content is listed. But this is not what I want, I mean I'd like to use an external XML file

Comment: Where is the external XML file stored? You just have to provide a valid Source for the XmlDataProvider. This could be for example the path to a local file or an URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried like this.... just have a look

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.Window4"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Window4" Height="300" Width="300">
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="BookmarkData" XPath="Hosts/Host">
        <x:XData>
            <Hosts>
                <Host>
                    <IP>1.1.1.1</IP>
                    <HostName>abc01</HostName>
                </Host>
                <Host>
                    <IP>2.2.2.2</IP>
                    <HostName>abc02</HostName>
                </Host>
            </Hosts>
        </x:XData>
    </XmlDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
  <Grid>
    <ListBox
           Background="#999"
           BorderThickness="2"
           BorderBrush="White" 
           Margin="10"
           DisplayMemberPath="HostName" 
           ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource BookmarkData}, XPath=/Hosts/Host}"
           />

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you forgot to specify a Data Context.

```
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource HostsData}}
```

either as a Grid xaml property, or Listbox.

And since the data comes from a XML provider, try to use the Xpath property tag

EDIT :

i found it more relevant to post a full example implementation, please ignore the Blend specific namespaces

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" x:Name="Screen_2_1_Name"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="WpfPrototype1Screens.Screen_2_1"
Width="640" Height="480">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="uneDataSource" Source="http://www.lemonde.fr/rss/une.xml" d:IsDataSource="True"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource uneDataSource}}">
    <ListBox Margin="80,88,64,112" Style="{DynamicResource ListBox-Sketch}" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/rss/channel/item/title}"/>
</Grid>
```